# Toggle Between Monitor Configurations

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 with a NVidia GeForce 1050. When I am developing, I use all four monitor outputs to work. However, if I am playing a game, I turn 1-3 of them off so that the card can have better performance. I don't mind turning them off, but every time I turn them back on it has forgotten the arrangement of the monitors and that one of them is supposed to be rotated 90 degrees. I looked into Disper, but they warn that it is not supported for more than two monitors. I don't need anything fanct, I'm just tired of rotating and arranging my monitors a few times a week.